# Where do I set IPN url in payPal?

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Maybe I am dumb, I have my sandbox account. There is a submenu called IPN simulator. That is ok, but I would like to find the IPN url in settings, that my transactions would go through my IPN url. I can't find this option in the sandbox? Am i blind or something?

Comment: Please share the form code that you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Login to PayPal (sandbox or live)
2. Go to My Profile
3. Select in the left panel "My Selling Tools"
4. In the section "Getting Paid and Managing My Risk" go to "Instant payment notifications" and click "update"
5. Insert the url for your IPN listener and select "Enable IPN"

Comment: not working 4/20/20, theres no 'my selling tools' for me